# Why nested function doesn't inherit this?

Tags: javascript, events, this

```
  const styleBackground = function () {
  console.log('ok')
  console.log(this)
}
const showDropdown = function () {
  console.log(this)
  styleBackground()
}
navItems.forEach(function (navItem) {
  navItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", showDropdown)
})
```

[console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Nx6.png)

Hello. Could someone explain me why this in nested function is the Window instead of an element?

nested function is it correct naming for styleBackground() calling in showDropdown (function inside a function)?

What is the best option to convey this to function inside a function?
styleBackground(this)  ?

thank you so much

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the function being "nested".  It's not clear from what you posted why you'd expect `this` to be anything other than `window` or `undefined`.

Comment: navItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", showDropdown) is executed in window context so this keyword will be window in your example. You shall pass the element as parameter if you want to make use of it in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the "bind" method if you want to especifically set "this" value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Basically, the context is infered in some cases but fallback to window.

Or use an arrow function instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this which preserves the context.